# Есть ли способ стилизации системных диалогов через DevExpress под WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Доброго дня!

При использовании DevExpress для WinForms есть возможность менять внешний вид приложения посредством LookAndFeel, но при этом все системные диалоги, например, OpenFileDialog остаются неизменными (не стилизованными).

Очень интересно, имеется ли возможность средствами самой библиотеки DevExpress привести внешний вид диалогов в соответствие с внешним видом самого приложения? Если да, то как это сделать?

*Грубо говоря, если у приложения используется тёмный скин, то и унифицированный вид диалога тоже должен быть тёмным.*

Comment: К сожалению, нет решения "из коробки". Ждем уже 11 лет: [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/AS5023).

Comment: Спасибо, тогда вопрос исчерпан!

Comment: @DmitryD. оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @andreycha выполнено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, нет решения "из коробки". Ждем уже 11 лет: [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/AS5023).

Comment: И вряд ли дождетесь, если посмотреть в исходники, например тут https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/b0695a987158f8e2.html, системные диалоги накрепко завязаны на WinApi и в .NET имеют только управляемую оболочку. Я может чего не понимаю, но по мне так их быстрее заменить самописными, чем натягивать кастомные темы на WinApi, но упорству ведь нет предела =)

Comment: А вот и дождались! Представлено в версии [17.2.2 beta](https://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/New-2017-2.xml?utm_source=Beta&utm_medium=WhatsNew&utm_campaign=v172&utm_content=v172_Beta_New#xtraeditors).